# Kibana server is not ready yet and logs shows "Unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

- New installation of elasticsearch and kibana on CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003
- kibana service displays ***`Kibana server is not ready yet`***

```
curl http://localhost:5601
Kibana server is not ready yet
```

- Elasticsearch version is : 7.9.2

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:9200
{
  "name" : "elkserver1",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "_na_",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.9.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "d34da0ea4a966c4e49417f2da2f244e3e97b4e6e",
    "build_date" : "2020-09-23T00:45:33.626720Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.6.2",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

- Kibana version

```
/usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana --version
7.9.2
```

- service is active and no errors

```
systemctl status kibana
● kibana.service - Kibana
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kibana.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-09-26 12:46:17 EDT; 9s ago
 Main PID: 22390 (node)
   CGroup: /system.slice/kibana.service
           └─22390 /usr/share/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node /usr/share/kibana/bin/../src/cli

Sep 26 12:46:17 elkserver1 systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
Sep 26 12:46:23 elkserver1 kibana[22390]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-09-26T16:46:23Z","tags":["warning","plugins-discovery"],"pid":22390,"message":"Expect plugin \"id\" in camelCase, but found: beats_management"}
Sep 26 12:46:23 elkserver1 kibana[22390]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-09-26T16:46:23Z","tags":["warning","plugins-discovery"],"pid":22390,"message":"Expect plugin \"id\" in camelCase, but found: triggers_actions_ui"}
```

- network.host & http.port lines are uncommented /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

```
cat /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml | grep 'network.host\|http.port'
network.host: localhost
http.port: 9200
```

- elasticsearch.hosts is uncommented in /etc/kibana/kibana.yml

```
cat /etc/kibana/kibana.yml | grep 'elasticsearch.hosts'
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
```

- firewalld is stopped and disabled
- Kibana logs shows **Unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms** but not sure what is causing this error.

```
journalctl --follow --unit kibana
-- Logs begin at Sat 2020-09-26 08:45:46 EDT. --
Sep 26 12:46:35 elkserver1 kibana[22390]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-09-26T16:46:35Z","tags":["warning","plugins","encryptedSavedObjects","config"],"pid":22390,"message":"Generating a random key for xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey. To be able to decrypt encrypted saved objects attributes after restart, please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml"}
Sep 26 12:46:35 elkserver1 kibana[22390]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-09-26T16:46:35Z","tags":["warning","plugins","ingestManager"],"pid":22390,"message":"Fleet APIs are disabled due to the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin using an ephemeral encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml."}
Sep 26 12:46:35 elkserver1 kibana[22390]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-09-26T16:46:35Z","tags":["warning","plugins","actions","actions"],"pid":22390,"message":"APIs are disabled due to the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin using an ephemeral encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml."}
Sep 26 12:46:35 elkserver1 kibana[22390]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-09-26T16:46:35Z","tags":["warning","plugins","alerts","plugins","alerting"],"pid":22390,"message":"APIs are disabled due to the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin using an ephemeral encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml."}
Sep 26 12:46:35 elkserver1 kibana[22390]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-09-26T16:46:35Z","tags":["info","plugins","monitoring","monitoring"],"pid":22390,"message":"config sourced from: production cluster"}
Sep 26 12:46:35 elkserver1 kibana[22390]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-09-26T16:46:35Z","tags":["warning","plugins","monitoring","monitoring"],"pid":22390,"message":"X-Pack Monitoring Cluster Alerts will not be available: X-Pack plugin is not installed on the Elasticsearch cluster."}
Sep 26 12:46:35 elkserver1 kibana[22390]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-09-26T16:46:35Z","tags":["info","savedobjects-service"],"pid":22390,"message":"Waiting until all Elasticsearch nodes are compatible with Kibana before starting saved objects migrations..."}
Sep 26 12:46:35 elkserver1 kibana[22390]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-09-26T16:46:35Z","tags":["info","savedobjects-service"],"pid":22390,"message":"Starting saved objects migrations"}
Sep 26 12:46:35 elkserver1 kibana[22390]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-09-26T16:46:35Z","tags":["warning","plugins","reporting","config"],"pid":22390,"message":"Chromium sandbox provides an additional layer of protection, but is not supported for Linux Centos 7.8.2003 OS. Automatically setting 'xpack.reporting.capture.browser.chromium.disableSandbox: true'."}
Sep 26 12:47:05 elkserver1 kibana[22390]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-09-26T16:47:05Z","tags":["warning","savedobjects-service"],"pid":22390,"message":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms"}
```

- any suggestions to solve this ?

Comment: what is the status of elasticsearch? Is there any error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Rohan . Thanks for the pointer. Finallay found the problem.

- Though curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:9200 was showing the elastic cluster status.
  Cluster  "cluster_uuid" was "*na*",.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:9200
{
  "name" : "elkserver1",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "_na_",    >>> Cluster_uuid 
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.9.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "d34da0ea4a966c4e49417f2da2f244e3e97b4e6e",
    "build_date" : "2020-09-23T00:45:33.626720Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.6.2",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

- journalctl --unit elasticsearch was showing "master not discovered or elected yet, an election requires a node with id [8G5Afwq7Qkqs7vUjSGTAfg], have discovered [{elkserver1}{VKd5Aef5SzyKLDfWFCzEqQ}"

```
[2020-09-28T13:29:56,862][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [elkserver1] master not discovered or elected yet, an election requires a node with id [8G5Afwq7Qkqs7vUjSGTAfg], have discovered [{elkserver1}{VKd5Aef5SzyKLDfWFCzEqQ}{IgEkTEsURfih_IKP299QWw}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=8201424896, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}] which is not a quorum; discovery will continue using [127.0.0.1:9301, 127.0.0.1:9302, 127.0.0.1:9303, 127.0.0.1:9304, 127.0.0.1:9305, [::1]:9301, [::1]:9302, [::1]:9303, [::1]:9304, [::1]:9305] from hosts providers and [{elkserver1}{VKd5Aef5SzyKLDfWFCzEqQ}{IgEkTEsURfih_IKP299QWw}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=8201424896, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}] from last-known cluster state; node term 1, last-accepted version 36 in term 1
```

- so it was a elastic search problem not kibana's issue. Since it is a new setup i have uninstalled elastic search and re-installed it . kibina started working after that .